# C++ SFML Unhandled exception when opening Windows font file

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio-2010, sfml

## Overview of Problem

I am working on a project which is to be used in a science lab for logging data. I wrote and compiled my code initially on Linux, and everything worked without any problems. I don't program on Windows usually (for good reason - you will see why soon), but unfortunately in this case the lab only has windows PC's so I have to migrate the project to Windows.

I've been working on this for several days, struggling with dynamic/static linking. I first tried with Code::Blocks, but although the program compiled and linked fine, it crashed at runtime because some standard library dll's didn't contain function entry points or something... So I changed to Visual Studio, and I think I have now got everything compiling and linking correctly ***in release mode (this is important for some reason I am not sure why?)***.

The problem I am having now is that the SFML function, `sf::Font.loadFromFile()` causes an *"unhandled Win32 exception"* when the program runs.

## Minimal Example

A lot of Stack Overflow users get abused when they fail to post a minimal example so I shall be careful to create an absolute minimal example in the hope that I do not fall down that rabbit hole.

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\Arial.ttf");
    return 0;
}
```

## Compile Link Details

I am compiling on a Windows XP laptop. I have Visual Studio 2010 installed. I am using SFML version 2.3.1-windows-vc10-32-bit. I have added the `include` directory to additional include directories in project settings. I have added the preprocessor definition `SFML_STATIC`, and I am linking with the static libs, eg; `sfml-system-s.lib`.

The order in which the linker options are listed in the VS project are:

```
winmm.lib
sfml-system-s.lib
opengl32.lib
gdi32.lib
sfml-window-s.lib
freetype.lib
jpeg.lib
sfml-graphics-s.lib
```

There are no warnings or errors when I build with `F7`. I hope that is enough information.

## Exact Error

[image: Error as shown on screen.]

I updated my graphics drivers yesterday.

Comment: Where are you defining your `font` variable?

Comment: @Shaktal Apologies, I went 1 step too minimal, one second please